# how to pass value of textbox into another page in asp.net (vb)

Tags: html, asp.net, vb.net

```
<form method = "post" action = "" runat="server">
                <p><asp:TextBox id="txtUser" runat="server" placeholder="Username"/></p>
                <p><asp:TextBox id="txtPass" runat="server" TextMode="Password" placeholder="Password"/></p>
                   <asp:Button id="btnLogin" Text="Login" runat="server" PostBackUrl ="~/Main.aspx" />
</form>
```

in above my code in login.aspx.

i want to get the username and password that i enter in login.aspx page and pass it to the string storage that i declare in Main.aspx page.

here my code in main.aspx:

```
<script runat="server">
    Dim txtUsername
    Dim txtPassword

    Sub Page_Load()

    End Sub
</script>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title>Untitled Page</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <h3><b><asp:Label ID="lblUser" runat="server" Text="Username: "></asp:Label>
            <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>
            </b></h3>
    </div>
        <h3><b><asp:Label ID="lblPass" runat="server" Text="Password: "></asp:Label>
            <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>
            </b></h3>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1.In the source page, save the information that you want to pass in session state, as shown in the following example:

```
 Session("password") = "value1"//txtPass.Text
Session("username") = "value2"//txtUser.Text
```

2.In the target page, read the saved information from session state, as shown in the following example:

```
 Dim password as String = CType(Session.Item("password"), String)
 Dim username as String = CType(Session.Item("username"), String)
```

you may refer the belowlink for more options..

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6c3yckfw.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-2

Comment: can i get two value in session state?

Comment: i want to get the username and password that entered.

Comment: you may use two sessions.

Comment: ok thanks. i'll try this first.. then i'll accept your answer.

Comment: Session("User") = txtUser.Text
        Session("Pass") = txtPass.Text                                                                   txtUsername = CType(Session.Item("User"), String)
        txtPassword = CType(Session.Item("Pass"), String)
        
        lblUsername.Text = txtUsername
        lblPassword.Text = txtPassword

Comment: Session("User") = txtUser.Text
        Session("Pass") = txtPass.Text

Comment: txtUsername = CType(Session.Item("User"), String)
        txtPassword = CType(Session.Item("Pass"), String)
        
        lblUsername.Text = txtUsername
        lblPassword.Text = txtPassword

Comment: thats the code that i tried.. just like youre but different declaration

Comment: refer this link http://www.aspdotnet-suresh.com/2012/11/aspnet-session-state-example-in-c-vbnet.html

Comment: thanks i got it.. your code is right.. the way i call my page_load in main.aspx page is wong.. i have missed some code there.. Thanks btw

Comment: :) glad to be at help